# How to access logger in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

One of the suggested approaches is to use Dependency Injection to inject logger to the constructor of the class. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html

However, what if my class is not registered with DI container or I just want to create a static logger per a class. How can I still access LoggerFactory which was configured in Startup.cs?

This is how I would do it using nlog:

```
private static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a static property in your `Startup` which exposes the `LoggerFactory`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //..
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

And then access it where you need a logger:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly ILogger _log = Startup.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyClass>();

    //..
}
```

Comment: Cool. That would do. I'd accept the answer if there is nothing more elegant available...